# How to show the success response from node server on react-redux framework

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am making a demo react-redux app for the basic understanding of redux and its server is made on nodeJS. I have made a simple form which gets submitted and the server response is `res.send('FORM SAVED')`. In front-end, I make the post request but is not able to see the response that returns, be it the success response.

My server controller that responds when form details are saved.

```
export const postData = (req, res) => {
    let p = new PostData();
    p.name = req.body.name;
    p.emp_id = req.body.emp_id;
    p.age = req.body.age;
    p.dept = req.body.dept;
    p.phone = req.body.phone;
    p.gender = req.body.gender;
    p.save(((err) => {
      if (err){res.send(`Error in uploading: ${err}`);}
      else {res.send('Form saved');}
    }));
}
```

This is my action:-

```
 export const createPost = postData => dispatch => {

  fetch(`${Config.address}/post`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(postData)
  })
  .then((post) => {
    console.log('post:', post);
    dispatch({
    type: NEW_POST,
    payload: post
  })
  })
}
```

This is how I call this in component after clicking submit:-

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

      let postData = {
        name: this.state.name,
        emp_id: this.state.emp_id,
        dept: this.state.dept,
        gender: this.state.gender,
        age: this.state.age,
        phone: this.state.phone
      }

      this.props.createPost(postData);
  }
```

I want to get the response string ('Form saved') but I don't know how to read that. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: When you do `console.log('post:', post);` what do you get in console?

Comment: `Response {type: "cors", url: "http://127.0.0.1:3002/api/post", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed : false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected : false
status:200
statusText:"OK"
type:"cors"
url:"http://127.0.0.1:3002/api/post"
__proto__: Response`

@TheReason

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns a *raw* response object. To get an expected data you should call a `.json()` method on *raw* response object which is returned by `fetch`, like below:

```
export const createPost = postData => dispatch => {
  fetch(`${Config.address}/post`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(postData)
  })
  .then(response => response.json()) // add this line
  .then((post) => {
    console.log('post:', post); // you should get an object with `Form saved` or something similar to it
    dispatch({
      type: NEW_POST,
      payload: postData // replace it to the input parameter
    })
  })
}
```

Using `async/await` it becomes more readable:

```
export const createPost = (postData) => async (dispatch) => {
  // send postData to server
  const rawResponse = await fetch(`${Config.address}/post`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(postData)
  });

  // we are done with server but we need one more step

  // turn a raw response to readable JS object
  const message = await rawResponse.json()

  // message from server response 
  console.log('Message ', message);

  // store same object as we sent to server in redux store
  dispatch({ type: NEW_POST, payload: postData });
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No, it did not work @TheReason. When I added `res=>res.json()` it returned the error `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0`